# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException when acessing list of lists

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I get the error `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 5`, however I double-checked the code and according to my understanding everything is correct. So, I cannot figure out how to solve the issue.

I have `RDD[(String,Map[String,List[Product with Serializable]])]`, such as:

```
(1566,Map(data1 -> List(List(1469785000, 111, 1, 3, null, 0),List(1469785022, 111, 1, 3, null, 1)), data2 -> List((4,88,1469775603,1,3370,f,537490800,661.09)))
```

I want to create a new RDD that will aggregate the values of 5th elements of sub-lists in `data1`:

```
Map(id -> 1566, type -> List(0,1))
```

I wrote the following code:

```
  val newRDD = currentRDD.map({
    line => Map(("id",line._1),
                ("type",line._2.get("data1").get.map(_.productElement(5))
               )
      })
```

If I put `_.productElement(0)`, then the result is `Map(id -> 1566, type -> List(1469785000,1469785022))`. So, I absolutely misunderstand why the 0th field can be accessed, while the 3rd, 4th, 5th fields provoke `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Rule of thumb, use full type annotations while learning and you will quickly find the solution yourself.

Comment: @sebszyller: What do you mean? Do you mean that I should avoid using `Product with Serializable`?

Comment: @sebszyller: The problem was due to `List[Product with Serializable]`, while I handled it as `List[List[Any]]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to `List[Product with Serializable]`, while I actually handled it as `List[List[Any]]`. I changed the initial RDD to `RDD[(String,Map[String,List[List[Any]]])]` and now everything works.